# Would I aggregate the time-series data based on front (top) and end (bottom)?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, aggregate

I would like to aggregate the data based on the front and end of them. Here is the data-set.

```
                  time      name
1  2019-07-07 15:01:00 SENSOR_07
2  2019-07-07 15:01:10 SENSOR_07
3  2019-07-07 15:01:20 SENSOR_07
4  2019-07-07 15:01:30 SENSOR_07
5  2019-07-07 15:01:40 SENSOR_07
6  2019-07-07 15:01:50 SENSOR_05
7  2019-07-07 15:02:00 SENSOR_05
8  2019-07-07 15:02:10 SENSOR_05
9  2019-07-07 15:02:20 SENSOR_07
10 2019-07-07 15:02:30 SENSOR_05
11 2019-07-07 15:02:40 SENSOR_07
12 2019-07-07 15:02:50 SENSOR_07
13 2019-07-07 15:03:00 SENSOR_07
14 2019-07-07 15:03:10 SENSOR_07
15 2019-07-07 15:03:20 SENSOR_07
```

> structure(list(time = structure(1:15, .Label = c("2019-07-07
>   15:01:00",  "2019-07-07 15:01:10", "2019-07-07 15:01:20", "2019-07-07
>   15:01:30",  "2019-07-07 15:01:40", "2019-07-07 15:01:50", "2019-07-07
>   15:02:00",  "2019-07-07 15:02:10", "2019-07-07 15:02:20", "2019-07-07
>   15:02:30",  "2019-07-07 15:02:40", "2019-07-07 15:02:50", "2019-07-07
>   15:03:00",  "2019-07-07 15:03:10", "2019-07-07 15:03:20"), class =
>   "factor"), 
>       name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("SENSOR_05", "SENSOR_07"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -15L))

The sensor name is assigned at every 10 seconds. In case of 1-5 row, it can be aggregated to the first row in expected table (SENSOR_07 between 15:01:00 to 15:01:50 just before SENSOR-05 existence). Here is the expected table.

```
           min_time                max_time          name
2019-07-07 15:01:00     2019-07-07 15:01:50     SENSOR_07
2019-07-07 15:01:50     2019-07-07 15:02:20     SENSOR_05
2019-07-07 15:02:20     2019-07-07 15:02:30     SENSOR_07
2019-07-07 15:02:30     2019-07-07 15:02:40     SENSOR_05
2019-07-07 15:02:40     2019-07-07 15:03:30     SENSOR_07
```

How do I make that using R code (using dplyr)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create groups using `lag` and `cumsum` and then select `first` and `last` value of `time`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(group = cumsum(name != lag(name, default = first(name)))) %>%
   summarise(min_time = first(time), 
             max_time = last(time), 
             name = first(name)) %>%
   select(-group)

#  min_time            max_time            name     
#  <fct>               <fct>               <fct>    
#1 2019-07-07 15:01:00 2019-07-07 15:01:40 SENSOR_07
#2 2019-07-07 15:01:50 2019-07-07 15:02:10 SENSOR_05
#3 2019-07-07 15:02:20 2019-07-07 15:02:20 SENSOR_07
#4 2019-07-07 15:02:30 2019-07-07 15:02:30 SENSOR_05
#5 2019-07-07 15:02:40 2019-07-07 15:03:20 SENSOR_07
```

However, it looks like you want to select max and min time for each sensor but your `time` column is `factor`. We can convert it into `POSIXct` class and then select `max` and `min` value from each group. Also if you want to have continuous values like end of one group should be start of another we can use `lead` to change value of `max_time`.

```
df %>%
   mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time)) %>%
   group_by(group = cumsum(name != lag(name, default = first(name)))) %>%
   summarise(min_time = min(time), 
             max_time = max(time), 
             name = first(name)) %>%
    mutate(max_time = lead(min_time, default = last(min_time))) %>%
    select(-group)

#  min_time            max_time            name     
#  <dttm>              <dttm>              <fct>    
#1 2019-07-07 15:01:00 2019-07-07 15:01:50 SENSOR_07
#2 2019-07-07 15:01:50 2019-07-07 15:02:20 SENSOR_05
#3 2019-07-07 15:02:20 2019-07-07 15:02:30 SENSOR_07
#4 2019-07-07 15:02:30 2019-07-07 15:02:40 SENSOR_05
#5 2019-07-07 15:02:40 2019-07-07 15:02:40 SENSOR_07
```